# How do I get data in twitter bootstrap progressbar from controller with thymeleaf? I'm kinda new to Spring-mvc and thymeleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to add data from my controller to present a progressbar in thymeleaf. I tried different approaches but none work.

```
<div class="progress progress-striped">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" **th:aria-valuenow="${model}"** aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" **th:style="@{'width:'+ ${percent} +';'}"**>
         <span class="sr-only">30% Complete (warning)</span>
     </div>
```

Comment: Found it : th:attr="aria-valuenow=${model}" th:style="'width:'+ ${percent}+';'"

Answer (score 3):

I tried using your answer and it didn't worked for me, but it helped to find an answer for me:

```
<div class="progress active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" th:attr="aria-valuenow=${p.value}" th:style="'width:'+ ${p.percent}+'%;'"></div>
</div>
```

p.value and p.percent are model attributes that I send from my controller. Both have numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Found it :

```
<div class="progress progress-striped">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" **th:aria-valuenow="${model}"** aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" th:attr="aria-valuenow=${model}" th:style="'width:'+ ${percent}+';'}">
     <span class="sr-only">30% Complete (warning)</span>
 </div>
```